# sendgrid dropping mails when adding 1000 mail ids to x-smtpapi

Tags: sendgrid

I am trying to add 1000 ids to x-smtpapi header. It is dropping out 20 mails in every run.

using the latest library. 
and code : myMessage.Headers.Add("x-smtpapi", header.JsonString());

I also tried inserting new line in place of comma, even then it drops out 20 mail ids in every run.

Sample dropped event list is as below. Have anyone faced the problem?
i 2016-03-17T16:48:01.000Z 2016-03-17T16:48:45.806Z 56eadfed6f31a23c66609e2e Invalid NikhilMysore008 dropped
JhieqlJdTfOuulniB77Itw@ismtpd0017p1sin1.sendgrid.net 59LKtSyLRvCQHT0JgZ7zlw 1458233280 filter0576p1mdw1.32212.56EADFA29.957 nikhil 2016-03-17T16:48:00.000Z 2016-03-17T16:48:45.800Z 56eadfed6f31a23c66609e0d Invalid NikhilMysore008 dropped
JhieqlJdTfOuulniB77Itw@ismtpd0017p1sin1.sendgrid.net e8c99aoaRFyfrkkz-0wbhg 1458233280 filter0576p1mdw1.32212.56EADFA29.924 nikhil0 2016-03-17T16:48:00.000Z 2016-03-17T16:48:45.794Z 56eadfed6f31a23c66609dec Invalid NikhilMysore008 dropped
JhieqlJdTfOuulniB77Itw@ismtpd0017p1sin1.sendgrid.net sAw_-aVORmO1wS6q7UPFPw 1458233279 filter0576p1mdw1.32212.56EADFA29.891 nikhil00 2016-03-17T16:47:59.000Z 2016-03-17T16:48:45.788Z 56eadfed6f31a23c66609dcb Invalid NikhilMysore008 dropped
JhieqlJdTfOuulniB77Itw@ismtpd0017p1sin1.sendgrid.net S9vnTT4qTFaoLeHk-sRu3w 1458233278 filter0576p1mdw1.32212.56EADFA29.858 nikhil008 2016-03-17T16:47:58.000Z 2016-03-17T16:48:45.783Z 56eadfed6f31a23c66609daa Invalid NikhilMysore008 dropped
JhieqlJdTfOuulniB77Itw@ismtpd0017p1sin1.sendgrid.net V2AwE_9tT8Krft22rOjqyA 1458233277 filter0576p1mdw1.32212.56EADFA29.825 nikhil0082 2016-03-17T16:47:57.000Z 2016-03-17T16:48:45.777Z 56eadfed6f31a23c66609d89 Invalid NikhilMysore008 dropped
JhieqlJdTfOuulniB77Itw@ismtpd0017p1sin1.sendgrid.net LYPPsiyiTLqvAFW_bGFHTg 1458233275 filter0576p1mdw1.32212.56EADFA29.726 nikhil00727@m 2016-03-17T16:47:55.000Z 2016-03-17T16:48:45.759Z 56eadfed6f31a23c66609d26 Invalid NikhilMysore008 dropped
JhieqlJdTfOuulniB77Itw@ismtpd0017p1sin1.sendgrid.net 7kd8QhwGRpCgi6w5QblknQ 1458233273 filter0576p1mdw1.32212.56EADFA29.693 nikhil00694@ma

Can see misformed email ids in the event logs.

Nikhil

Answer (score 0):

`JhieqlJdTfOuulniB77Itw@ismtpd0017p1sin1.sendgrid.net` means that you're sending to `JhieqlJdTfOuulniB77Itw`, which is an invalid address. What in your system is generating that code?

When sending a large X-SMTPAPI header, make sure you're wrapping the lines with a CRLF (`\r\n`). THat way they'll be unwrapped & processed properly.

Comment: I am inserting CRLF between mail ids. Still this is happening.